# Fourier transform of an exponentially singular radial function

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, spherical-coordinates, regularization

I am trying to compute the 3D Fourier transform of a spherically symmetric function of the form 
$$f(r) = e^{\frac{1}{r} e^{-r}} - 1\, ,$$
which entails the integral
$$\begin{aligned}F(k) =& \int d^3\!r \, e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} f(r) \\
       =& \int_0^\infty dr\!\int_0^{\pi}\!d\theta\!\int_0^{2\pi}\!d\phi \, r^2 \sin\theta \, e^{-ikr\cos{\theta}} f(r) \\
 = & \, 2 \pi \int_0^\infty\! dr \, r^2 f(r) \int_0^{\pi}\!d\theta  \sin\theta \, e^{-ikr\cos{\theta}}  \\
=& \, 4\pi \int_0^\infty\!\! dr \, r^2 \mathrm{sinc}(kr) \, f(r) \,.\end{aligned}  $$
Based on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80857/fourier-transform-of-expexpx), I'm inclined to think that this integral will not converge even if I attempt to regularize it because exponent grows without bound near $r=0$. However, since the integral is not a usual Fourier transform, I'm holding out hope that the integral converges, though by what means, I do not know. My main questions are then:

1. Is the reasoning within the linked answer applicable to this "3D" Fourier transform? That is, does this spherically symmetric function follow the same convergence rules as that of a one-dimensional cartesian-coordinate function?
2. If the link answer does not apply here, what tools are available to try to compute this transform? I can readily accept a good approximation, as this is with regards to a physics problem.

Comment: I think you mean "entails" instead of "entrails" ;)

Comment: Well, there's no shortage of those lying about after hacking away at this, either. :)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says the integral diverges. Taylor expanding $f$ near $r=0$ and approximating $e^x \approx 1 + x$ has $f(r)\approx \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1 - rk)/(k!r^k).$ My guess is that since this series $f$ has terms of the form $r^{-k}$ for all $k$, you're out of luck. (Do mind that this isn't a proof, though!)

Comment: @Neal Sure, Wolfram Alpha also claims that the transform of 1/x diverges if you put in the explicit integral, but surely it has a transform (as does 1/r for the 3D case).